# Dataset organization for Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, dataset, conv-neural-network, organization

Is there anyone who can give me the right links for data organization for **Convolutional Neural Network**, please? I searched myself, I was looking for an article about that topic from towardsdatascience.com but did not found it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need, but are you looking for a specific structure of a CNN?

Comment: Yes,i think. Just leave me what you have,probably it will be useful.